# How to get the X, Y values from the given Z value after using interpolate.interp2d to plot a surface

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have x and y arrays to represent the row and column of a grid data and its values are in the z 2d array. 
I have used interpolate.interp2d to plot a surface graph.
Now, I am able to obtain the z value for given x, y value but I want to be able to obtain the x,y values from the given z value.

code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy import interpolate

x = [0, 0.01, 0.02]
y = [0, 5e-05, 0.0001]
print(np.meshgrid(x, y))
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = [[ 1.    ,      0.99990035,  0.99981654],
 [ 0.90849264,  0.85447203,  0.81382534],
 [ 0.82880434 , 0.76083003 , 0.71961281]]
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='linear')
xnew = np.arange(x[0],x[2], 1e-6)
ynew = np.arange(y[0],y[2], 1e-6)

znew = f(xnew, ynew)
print(f(0.003,0.0006))
xnew,ynew=np.meshgrid(xnew,ynew)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(xnew,ynew, znew,
                       cmap=cm.get_cmap('coolwarm'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: As seen from the picture, given some z value there are infinitely many points (x,y) that have this z value. So it's a bit unclear what you are trying to get at.

Comment: I want a surface that cuts through the given surface representing the x,y plane corresponding to the given z value

Comment: Wouldn't that be a line, rather than a surface?

Comment: It could be a surface (e.g. `(x,y) for x in [0,10] and y in [10,20]`), it could be a line (e.g. `y=2x+1`), it could be random points (e.g. `(1,3)` and `(4,8)`) it could be any combination of the above or none. there is absolutely no way of knowing without having some information about the function `f(x,y)->z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you anyway plot the surface you may add a contour plot along a specific `z` value. In order to obtain the x,y values from that given z value, ob can then use the contour line's data.

```
c = ax.contour(xnew,ynew,znew, [f(0.003,0.0006)])
line = c.allsegs[0][0]
print(line)
```

The resulting `line` is a 2D array with the x values in the first and the y values in the second column.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy import interpolate

x = [0, 0.01, 0.02]
y = [0, 5e-05, 0.0001]
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = [[ 1.    ,      0.99990035,  0.99981654],
    [ 0.90849264,  0.85447203,  0.81382534],
    [ 0.82880434 , 0.76083003 , 0.71961281]]

f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='linear')

xnew = np.arange(x[0],x[2], 1e-6)
ynew = np.arange(y[0],y[2], 1e-6)
znew = f(xnew, ynew)
print(f(0.003,0.0006))
xnew,ynew=np.meshgrid(xnew,ynew)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(xnew,ynew, znew,
                       cmap=cm.get_cmap('coolwarm'))

c = ax.contour(xnew,ynew,znew, [f(0.003,0.0006)])
line = c.allsegs[0][0]
print(line)
ax.view_init(elev=13, azim=18)
plt.show()
```

[image]